# Conditional Independence question

Tags: probability, random-variables

$A, B, C, D$ are discrete random variables, is it true that $\def\indep{\perp\hspace{-1.25ex}\perp}A \indep B,C \mid D$ implies $A \indep B\mid D$ ?

Comment: Can you please correct your question: e.g., what do you mean $C|D$?

Comment: $A\perp\hspace{-1.25ex}\perp B,C\mid D$ means $A$ and $B\cap C$ are conditionally independent given $D$.

Answer (score 0):

No, I have a counter example. Set $A \perp C$ and $B = A \cup C$ and $P(D)=1$. $B\cap C = C$ so $A$ and $B\cap C$ are conditionally independent given $D$. However, $A$ and $B$ are conditionally dependent given $D$ because if $A$ happens, you know that $B$ happens too.

Comment: Thank you so much!